# Using Nvidia OpenCL-drivers with an ICD-loader on Windows

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia, msys2

I have configured Installable Client Drivers (ICDs) on an Ubuntu-distribution with Intel OpenCL runtime drivers, which was fairly straightforward. These drivers come as *.so-files which can be loaded by specifying their path in an `*.icd`-file under `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/`.

How would I proceed to specify Nvidia OpenCL-drivers on Windows, and where are these drivers located?

I use MINGW64 with and OpenCL-ICD-Loader installed via [MSYS2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-opencl-icd)

Where is the corresponding directory to add the `*.icd`-files?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows with MinGW-w64 I use a combination of:

- https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers
- https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader

OpenCL-ICD-Loader figures out where to load the Nvidia stuff from.

To build from source I had to tweak some stuff, see my build recipes:

- https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/khronos-opencl-headers.winlib
- https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/khronos-opencl-icd-loader.winlib

Answer (score 0):

You can specify drivers (ICDs) through the Windows registry by creating a REG_DWORD with the full path to the *.dll driver as name.
A value of 0 enables the driver.
A value of 1 disables the driver.

```
// For 32-bit operating systems, or 64-bit tests on a 64-bit operating system:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors

// For 32-bit tests on a 64-bit operating system:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors

// The name of the REG_DWORD value should be the full path to the library of your implementation, for eg.
// OpenCLDriverStub.dll, and the data for this value should be 0.
```